# What is the usage of Signalr

Tags: signalr

Im wants to make a live chat feature in my web applicatin in asp.net. I found signalr for live chat, but i want to save that text from one browser to How to save text user's message in signalr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR is used to push changes to the client.  Saving messages is not a concern for SignalR.  You need to roll your own persistence for  this,  maybe your application have a database already?

Comment: Yes my application having database, but i want to save users messages using signalr , is it possible to save message at browser or what should i do?

Comment: You could look at the HTML5 File api. It really depends on what browsers you want to support, the user experience and finally your technical architecture. But since the data is local, it seems best to try and write it locally, instead of sending it to the server, for the single purpose of creating is as a file.